# Handling large amount of data and processes in multiprocessing

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, large-files

So after long considerations and try-outs, I'm once again asking the pros.
My scenario looks like that: I want to compare two datasets (np arrays, ca. 2000^3) with some function. This comparison has to be done for ca 1000 random points with 300 different settings each. The second dataset holds values for a breaking condition of this measurements, so that every worker has to know the whole dataset and the mask.

My idea, as I have 64 CPUs and 200+GB of RAM looks like that

```
def compare(point,setting,data,mask): 
    if mask[point]==somevalue:
        for i in setting:
            do.something(data)


def parallel():
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)
    for i in range(points):
        pool.apply_async(compare, args = (point,setting,data,mask), callback = some_call)
    pool.close()
    pool.join() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parallel()
```

which seems to work for small datasets, but not for datasets in the range desired. The workers seem to be applied to the pool and the pool is closed, but then nothing happens. I think, that there should be a way, to have the data and mask array somehow stored, so that every worker can access them, without passing them explicitly to each worker(maybe memory mapping?). Or is the problem something else?

I hope, to have explained the problem well enough, if not, I'm trying my best to clarify.

Comment: Are any errors getting thrown, or is the pool just silently closing itself? In either case, it might be a good idea to put a big `try/except` in `compare` and write any errors out to a file.

Comment: As far is I can tell, It's working without any problems for small arrays, even for huge numbers of points and more than 100 workers. I will look for your try/except idea, but the first line of compare never is reached for big sizes of data.

Comment: Ok- something else to try is instead of sending your data via `apply_async` (in the `args` tuple), can you read it from a file in `compare`? There are issues with trying to send large amounts of data between processes in this way because Python uses `pickle` to send the data

Comment: The thing is, that I have the data already in memory, so can I just use a global variable which holds the data? (Gonna try your answer, nevertheless)

Comment: Global variables which are module-level constants work fine, but only if they are small enough, so the exact same issue is present here as well. Read these guidelines...basically the less sharing of resources and interprocess communication, the better: http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#all-platforms

Comment: Actually, for me, using the arrays as global variables has done the trick (despite being huge), so I might accept that as an answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35096/discussion-between-dschoni-and-mdscruggs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just using a global variable to store your common arrays and allow the forking/subprocess behavior of inheriting parent process data to do your work for you (although note this may not work if your arrays are REALLY REALLY big). This might get around the issue of pickling large amounts of data via the `Process` constructor.

Comment: Why is that and what is really big?